# Reference array in json

Tags: php, arrays, json

How can I reference this array

```
{
  "item1": "test1",
  "item2": test2,
  "item3": [
        {
         "item3-1": "test3-1",
         "item3-2": "test3-2"
        }
}
```

I've tried

```
foreach($rec as $rlls=>$rll)
{
  $test             = $rll[0]['item3']['item3-1'];
}
```

But no luck

Thanks

---

Thank you, I was using $value instead of $a. How can I loop over it if the array is like this.

```
"item3": [
        {
         "item3-1": "test3-1",
         "item3-2": "test3-2"
        },
        {
         "item3-3": "test3-3",
         "item3-4": "test3-4"
         }
```

Thanks

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: @robert Do you want to access to every values ? every values of the "item3" key ? or just the value corresponding to the "item3-1" key ?

Comment: all the items, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>    {
>      "item1": "test1",
>      "item2": test2,
>      "item3": [
>            {
>             "item3-1": "test3-1",
>             "item3-2": "test3-2"
>            }    }
> ```

First, your JSON is invalid. In PHP the fixed version will look like this:

```
$s = <<<'EOS'
{
  "item1": "test1",
  "item2": "test2",
  "item3": [
    {
      "item3-1": "test3-1",
      "item3-2": "test3-2"
    }
  ]
}
EOS;
```

To traverse this JSON string you'll need to [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it first:

```
if (! ($a = json_decode($s, true))) {
  // Handle error
}
```

Then run the loop or access the items directly:

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
  echo "Key: $key\n";
  echo "Value:", (is_array($value) ? var_export($value, true) : $value), "\n";
}

echo $a['item3'][0]['item3-1'];
```